# Can we have a "Part time permanent" option under "What type of work are you seeking?"

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Some crazy people love programming, but they also have other things in their life, perhaps even to the extent that they want to work part time. Or is it just me?

Comment: Yeah, what about all of us who enjoy boating!

Comment: I agree.  I am a grad student with 3 years of industry experience, so I am seeking part-time permanent work.

Answer (score 12):

I agree. The options currently available are

- Full time permanent
- Temporary contract
- Telecommute
- Internship or Co-op

it even promises "part-time" in the help text on the edit page!