# Serve careers widgets for people to embed in their sites

Tags: feature-request, jobs

How about careers serving HTML snippets and JavaScript embeds for people to put into their own sites, CVs, and profiles?

That way, people who have a CV outside careers wouldn't have to maintain two data sets; the JavaScript snippets could also come as pre-styled `iframe`s, which is nice if you're not big on design. (But please serve pure HTML as well for people to style themselves.)

The benefit for careers is obvious: You tie your users to your service even more closely; users have even more reason to keep their data up to date; the embeds drive potential employers to the site.

Possible features (feel free to edit and/or make CW):

**Embeddable**

- A careers flair showing top x% positions. Something like this:

  [image]

  Maybe show a careers logo on that one - bragging is so much easier when it's a third party providing the facts. :)
- A careers flair showing key data

  [image]
- A styled JS embed for the "experience" table, like so:

  [image]
- A styled JS embed for the "education" table

**Raw HTML:**

- Full profile
- Experience
- Education
- Bookshelf
- Pretty much every other section, in nice semantic HTML of course.

Comment: By the way, thanks to the careers team for handling feature and support requests in a consistently friendly and verbose way, be they implementation-worthy or not!

Comment: @Pekka I'm having trouble telling if that's sarcastic or not...

Comment: @David not at all!  (I *do* have an unanswered careers request that I'd appreciate some feedback on, I'll dig that up in a minute. But that is totally unrelated) The vast majority of careers related questions receives offical attention quickly, and satisfyingly.

Comment: @David this one. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25082/can-we-have-a-part-time-permanent-option-under-what-type-of-work-are-you-seeki

Comment: The first image is broken. :(

Comment: @Justin fixed - I just had to replace the imgur URL by the Stack Overflow specific one.

Comment: +1 I suppose you also program in limericks too ;-)

Comment: Has there been any movement on this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I like this idea, but it's only worth doing if people are going to use it.  So if you would use this **vote it up**.

Comment: @David yeah. I implemented this for a portal once, and I know how huge the effort is. We'll see whether it can amass enough support.

Comment: @David - I think it would be a lot like flair. Once people realize they _can_ do it, many probably will. Cuz, you know, making a new widget on your blog and pasting in some code is _totally_ easier than clicking upvote.

Comment: Now with examples!

Comment: @Pekka cool examples

Comment: I would definitely use this if I ever got a website and an invitation to careers.

Comment: @jcolebrand Thanks for the offer, but I already got an invite from SO itself.  :)  Unfortunately, I still can't use this widget yet as I don't have a website or CV to put it on yet.

Comment: @John, ah, there you go then.