# Careers 2.0 Widget

Tags: feature-request, jobs, widgets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serve widgets from careers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87618/serve-widgets-from-careers)

What does the community think of widgets for careers? I would love it if I could have a widget on my blog. The flair widget exists , but the careers page has so much more info about me. This would also be useful as a link to an awesome online resume.