# Careers 2.0 Badge for External Websites

Tags: feature-request, jobs

If you go to blogs and personal websites they often have "badges" that link back to things like LinkedIn. These are useful for directing people back to your profiles. I would like the same thing for Careers 2.0.

An example of my LinkedIn "badge" is

```
<a href="http://ca.linkedin.com/pub/rob-veldpaus/31/45a/476">
    <img src="http://www.linkedin.com/img/webpromo/btn_viewmy_160x33.png" width="160" height="33" border="0" alt="View Rob Veldpaus's profile on LinkedIn">
</a>
```

Comment: Closely related: [Serve careers widgets for people to embed in their sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87618)