# flair for careers?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, flair

Is there "[flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22470/powtac/flair)" for [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/powtac)? Else my badge list on http://www.bruechner.de looks incomplete.

Comment: Short answer: nope.

Comment: Related: [Serve careers widgets for people to embed in their sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87618)

Comment: Until they implement a widget as suggested by Pekka you can use the [logo](http://careerscdn.sstatic.net/careers/Img/logo-careers-2-small.png) and just link it to your careers profile.

Comment: Is the website link *really* needed here ?

Comment: @AshRj can't see any harm in this, he's not trying to self promote himself and it indeed look weird that all other items have images while the link to Careers is text only. Makes it look somewhat less professional.