# Part-time work on SO Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

In my SO Careers profile I can tick what types of work I'm interested in (see screenshot below). As I would also like to have the option to look for part-time employment, I was thinking about possible ways to improve this list.

My suggestions:

- make *full-time* and *permanent contract* separate options
- add options *part-time* or alternatively *preferred working hours per week: X* (where X can either be picked from a set values or any number between, say, 1 and 40)

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25082/179891